# Azure CosmosDB - partition strategy for dictionary-like object collections

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We need to move out a huge amount of data from our memory cache as it takes too much space. For that purpose, we are considering CosmosDB. The data structure and use cases are provided at the bottom. While testing it I get a few issues I can't solve: Single item retrieval takes too long (around 2 seconds), transactions seem like costing more RU then it should and can't decide on optimal throughput. 
So, I have these questions:

1. How partitioning should be handled with the provided data structure? And if it even would have an effect?
2. General throughput during the week should be low (few hundreds of requests per second), but we anticipate that in a timely manner there will be spikes on requests (dozens of times more). How can we configure the container to bypass the risk of throttling and not overpay when usage is low?
3. Should I consider an alternative?

```
[
  {
    id: '<unique_id>',
    hash: '<custom_hash>'
    data: [{}, {},...]
  },
  ...
]
```

There are three use cases for the collection:

1. Read whole collection and taking id's and hash'es to identify which items changed
2. Replace/insert batch of items if there are changes
3. Read single item retrieving data property values

Comment: I have some questions. How much data are you storing? Are you using Cosmos SQL API and making the id the partition key? Are you querying for data using the id? Thanks.

Comment: Under 10GB (should be around 3GB), I am using SQL API only to query whole container, for specific items I use method GetItemAsync. I made id into partition key (tried using fake field with constant value too), and yes I am querying by id.

Comment: Are you passing the partition key value in the the GetItemAsync request options? Also how large is each item on average? Thanks.

Comment: To be more precise I used ReadItemAsync, and yes I used partition key as request option "container.ReadItemAsync(id, new PartitionKey(id))". Item on average should be around 3kb